# Build has been canceled

Tags: visual-studio

I am having trouble compiling a default project using visual studio 2010 professional 64bit. When I run a new web application for asp.net or asp.net mvc, I get the following error in the output window.

> ------ Build started: Project: WebApplication1, Configuration: Debug
>   Any CPU ------ Build has been
>   canceled.

Answer (score 15):

Was JsLint and the default option 'cancel on build'

Comment: Can't imagine how long it would have taken me to track that down w/o this answer. I hope it didn't take you too long.

Comment: Wow, same thing happened to me - thanks! I never would have figured this out on my own.  Why in the world would I want something that checks my javascript to prevent me from building my server-side code?  What a strange default option.

Comment: This hit me too but I didn't twig, as I'd forgotten that I has installed the JS Lint for Visual Studio 2010 v1.2.4.0. I ended up doing a binary chop excluding stuff to make the sln build (MvCMusicStoreSample) Menu->Tools->JS Line Options ...->Cancel Build on error should be false

Comment: I got the same without JsLint. Any idea where would be the problem ? I got Roslynator, resharper (desactivated), ndepend, but to my knowledge (and after exploration), there was no such option. The first build (rebuild) is successful, but after a new F5, I got the 'build canceled' without error. Webpack takes care of the React part, and there is not problem there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried executing the build from the command line using MSBuild.exe?  You can better tweak the debug level and perhaps learn more about where the build is failing.  For example, executing this from the command line:

Msbuild.exe WebApplication1.csproj /verbosity:detailed

Will give you more data than just building in visual studio.  If that isn't enough, you can change the "detailed" to "diagnostic" and learn even more (though, that will be hard to read).

I think (though I could be wrong) what you get in the visual studio window is "minimal" verbosity, which often hides some important facts.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Although years after the original question, this might help someone else.

Another cause of this can be the length of an output path.  You can get this problem without it being obvious if your projects file paths are >just< small enough to fit within the limit, but when building, the extra paths (/obj/debug and the like) go over the limit.

The fix, obviously, is to move the root of your solution as close to root as possible (i.e. try using C:\a[your solution]).

If this is still too long then you've got problems.

Annoying that VS doesn't explain this, even with diagnostic level logging.